# Xamarin ListView (not Forms) binding only appears in one cell

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a ListView implemented in C# in an Android Xamarin page. Each ListView item has labels and bound data. When rendered, the labels show fine in all items, but the bound data only shows in the last item (the others are blank).
I have verified that the data is in the list being used as the data source.

I have virtually the same page implemented in XAML and it works fine. I don't understand why only one item is being populated in the C# version.

I did notice that I get a number of "requestLayout() improperly called by ..." errors on the C# implementation when running, but have been unable to figure out why this is.

```
    public EditRoutines()
    {
        Title = "Edit Routines";

        Label label0 = new Label { Text = "Count: ", TextColor = Color.Gray, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.None, FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label)) };

        lName = new Label { TextColor = Color.Blue, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.None, FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label)) };
        lName.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "name");

        lCount = new Label {  TextColor = Color.Gray, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.None, FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label)) };
        lCount.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "count");

        lDuration = new Label { TextColor = Color.Gray, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.None, FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label)) };
        lDuration.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "duration");

        lInterval = new Label { TextColor = Color.Gray, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.None, FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label)) };
        lInterval.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "interval");

        DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            StackLayout sl = new StackLayout
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                Children = {
                    new StackLayout
                    {
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                        Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                        Children = {
                            lName,
                            new StackLayout
                            {
                                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                                Children = {
                                    new Label { Text="Count: ", TextColor=Color.Gray, FontAttributes= FontAttributes.None, FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label)) },                        
                                    lCount
                                }
                            },
                            new StackLayout
                            {
                                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                                Children = {
                                    new Label { Text = "Duration: ", TextColor=Color.Gray, FontAttributes= FontAttributes.None, FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label))},
                                    lDuration
                                }
                            },
                            new StackLayout
                            {
                                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                                Children = {
                                    new Label { Text = "Interval: ", TextColor=Color.Gray, FontAttributes= FontAttributes.None, FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label)) },
                                    lInterval
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };


            return new ViewCell() { View = sl };
        });

        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Margin = new Thickness(20),
            Children = {
            new ListView { ItemsSource = Global.routines.routineList, ItemTemplate = dt, Margin = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0), HasUnevenRows = true }
            }
        };

    }
```

Here is the XAML that works.

```
<ListView x:Name="listviewRoutines" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemSelected="listviewRoutines_ItemSelected">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackLayout Padding="5,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" >
                        <Label Text="{Binding name}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" TextColor="Blue"  FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Default"/>
                        <!--
                        <Label Text="{Binding description}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" TextColor="Gray"  FontAttributes="None" FontSize="Small"/>
                        -->
                        <StackLayout Padding="5,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="Count: "  TextColor="Gray"  FontAttributes="None" FontSize="Small"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding count}" TextColor="Gray"  FontAttributes="None" FontSize="Small"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Padding="5,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="Duration: "  TextColor="Gray"  FontAttributes="None" FontSize="Small"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding duration}" TextColor="Gray"  FontAttributes="None" FontSize="Small"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Padding="5,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="Interval: "  TextColor="Gray"  FontAttributes="None" FontSize="Small"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding interval}" TextColor="Gray"  FontAttributes="None" FontSize="Small"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Padding="5,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="When: "  TextColor="Gray"  FontAttributes="None" FontSize="Small"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding when}" TextColor="Gray"  FontAttributes="None" FontSize="Small"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Unfortunately we cant see the code, so we have no idea of knowing whats going on. We cant see the implementation that works, nor the one that doesn't . All we can do is rely on the fact that you have done this right without mistakes and go hmm. is it possible to add code to this question in a minimal and verifiable way? If not this question will end up as too broad

Comment: we can't debug code we can't see

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the problem. The bound values are declared outside of the DataTemplate which apparently causes the listview to only display the last value in the list. I move the declarations inside the DataTemplate and it now works properly.